# Can't install apc on wamp2.2 on a windows 7 x64 machine, wamp is also x64. Help please

Tags: php, apache, wamp, apc

I’ve been trying to install apc on wamp 2.2 on a windows 7 x64 to no avail. I downloaded php_apc without memprotect and was able to select it in the task switcher on wamp, I also added the extension and the following:

```
[APC]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 64M
apc.max_file_size = 10M
apc.stat = 1
```

to php.ini, next, downloaded apc.php from http://svn.php.net, but my phpinfo() file doesn’t show apc no matter what I do, and apc.php says it isn’t running.

I've read about wamp being built on vc6 but on pierre's php extensions page I can't find any vc6 version anymore, plus I have php5.4.3 with the MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008) compiler, so I figure I must not install a vc6 version. But I can't find any information about wamp and alternative php cache (thats the full name!). All the pages where I've read about it make it seem very simple, but I can't make it work. I need apc to deal with the nicEdit image uploading, by the way. Any help would make me very, very happy!

Also, I notice a couple of things, many posts right here on this forum say that apc is not supported by php 5.4, and on other posts people say that for windows we should use vc6 versions either of php or its extensions. The thing is I'm using wamp as I said, and don't want to go through the process of installing php and apache independently. Even if I did, then what dll should I download (after searching a lot, as pecl doesn't provide dlls), also considering that I can't afford for a server other than apache and it is recommended not to install any vc9 version of php with apache's binaries?
Again, any help is greatly appreciated.

Think I finally got it, @eis you were right about installing the correct x64bit extension. I downloaded the correct one from the list of extensions hosted in mediafire on this http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ site. Now I can see apc is installed on phpinfo();
Thanks and goodbye.
Will keep posting about the usage of apc though.

Comment: "The thing is I'm using wamp as I said, and don't want to go through the process of installing php and apache independently." - just noting that installing them independendly is like a 2 minute job, provided that you check where te enable mod_php (or similar). You get a lot better understanding, in my opinion, about your system and how to resolve issues like these.

Comment: also, you didn't post the configuration about where you've enabled the dll. you have done that, right? check out the instructions [here](http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Installing_APC_in_Windows). You should first download the dll, enable that, and check if phpinfo is showing it as enabled before you proceed.

Comment: 3rd note - the dlls on pierres page seem to be x86. you need a 64-bit dll. or switch to a 32-bit server installation.

Comment: @eis Think I finally got it,  you were right about installing the correct x64bit extension. I downloaded the correct one from the list of extensions hosted in mediafire on this http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ site. Now I can see apc is installed on phpinfo(); Thanks and goodbye. Will keep posting about the usage of apc though.

Comment: Ok, great. I posted it as answer, so this can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a resolution - the dlls on pierres page seem to be 32-bit (x86). Since you have a 64-bit server, you need either a 64-bit dll, or switch to a 32-bit server installation.

The [anindya.com page](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/) had a link to [64-bit extensions](http://www.mediafire.com/php-win64-extensions).

Comment: Can you please detail what exactly did you do? Which file did you downloaded from that mediafire folder and what exactly did you on wamp side? I'm having the same issue and I cannot make it work :( ps: where is the apc.php on http://svn.php.net/ ? Thanks!

Comment: @Ka7anax um, I didn't do anything except posted the information here. I've never even had WAMP installed.

Comment: These files don't work. Wampserver will not load after restart.

Comment: @AndrewU they were verified working by OP at the time of the question, but it may very well be that they no longer work. However the answer is still correct, for a 64-bit server 64-bit extensions are needed.

Comment: After several alternatives, I found the hint here that the brother helped me a lot, I use the 64-bit structure wamp and not enabled the "APC" the problem was the link dll x86 "64-bit extension" found the solution, the php_apc.dll 64 bit and it worked. 
Thank you!